# Дублируются точки подключения при автоконекте к Wifi

Tags: java, android, wifi

Пишу автоконект к `wifi`.

Уже убил кучу времени, а корректной работы так и не добился. В списке точек подключения появляется куча точек с одинаковым именем.

Вот код подключения:

```
registerReceiver(connectionReceiver, intentFilter); 
int networkId = wifi.getConnectionInfo().getNetworkId(); 
wifi.removeNetwork(networkId); 
int netId = wifi.addNetwork(conf); 
wifi.enableNetwork(netId, true); 
wifi.reconnect(); 
unregisterReceiver(this);
```

[Вот полный код](https://github.com/QitmentX7/android-wifi-activity/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/zoltanersek/androidwifiactivity/WifiBaseActivity.java)
Буду очень благодарен любой помоши и совету!!!
[image: Дублирование wifi точек]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ура! Я нашол решение! Я должен удалять все записи этой точки:

```
List<WifiConfiguration> list = wifi.getConfiguredNetworks();
                    for( WifiConfiguration i : list ) {
                        wifi.removeNetwork(i.networkId);
                        wifi.saveConfiguration();
                    }
                    int netId = wifi.addNetwork(conf);
                    wifi.enableNetwork(netId, true);
                    wifi.reconnect();
```